# Definition of function (Michael spivak)

Tags: calculus, functions

In Michael spivak book (calculus) especially in the chapter that talking about functions.

He began with a provisional definition which is the function is a (rule) and in the end of the chapter he clarified the defects in the provisional definition.

Then he talked about that functions realte sets to each other and that for every (x) there is [f(x)] but what I don't grasp how he defined it as sets of ordered pairs.

So can one explain explicitly why it's defined like this and the reasoning and intuition behind this definition.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE! <> In words, Spivak's definition identifies a function with its graph (a set of ordered pairs).

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang 
but I've read that the relation is also defined by this definition

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang 
So what is the rigorous definition of the function Regardless its graph ?

Comment: Nowadays the ordered pair definition is standard. Classically one thought of a function as a "rule." The ordered pair definition is a way of expressing the concept of a rule in terms of set theory.

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang but the concept of rule is an ambiguous and vague one and that what mathematics seeks to avoid

Comment: The ambiguity and vagueness of "rules" is precisely why mathematicians introduced the modern definition of $f$ as a set of ordered pairs $(x, y)$ such that for every $x$ there exists a unique $y$ such that $(x, y) \in f$. <> Maybe I misunderstood what you were asking? I thought you wanted to understand the intuition behind the "ordered pairs" definition of a function.

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang 
Thanks for your help
''Maybe I misunderstood what you were asking? I thought you wanted to understand the intuition behind the "ordered pairs" definition of a function'' that's exactly what I wanted but saddly your first comment didn't solve my problem so if you can mention any book that talks about this stuff I will be thankful to you

Answer (score 1):

We say that $(a,\ b)$ is an ordered pair with the elements $a$ and $b$ grouped together with the following specification: $a$ is the first element in the pair and $b$ is the second. Two ordered pairs $(a,\ b)$ and $(c,\ d)$ are equal if and only if $a = b$ and $c = d$. In other words, each element in both ordered pairs has to match in the exact order such that $(a,\ b) = (c,\ d)$.

An ordered pair in the form of $(a,\ b)$ can be defined as a set in the form follows:
$$
(a,\ b) = \{\{a\},\ \{a,\ b\}\}
$$
If $a \neq b$, the elements in the set are distinct and each can be distinguished from each other. Since $a$ is in both $\{a\}$ and $\{a,\ b\}$ while $b$ is not, we can say that $a$ is the first element of the pair and $b$ the second. If $a = b$, we simply define the set as $\{\{a\}\}$ and indicate the ordered pair as $(a,\ a)$. Note that the Cartesian plane is relatable to ordered pairs.

Here comes Michael Spivak's definition of a function:

> A **function** is a collection of pairs of numbers with the following property: if $(a,\ b)$ and $(a,\ c)$ are both in the collection, then $b = c$; in other words, the collection must not contain two different pairs with the same first element.

> If $f$ is a function, the **domain** of $f$ is the set of all $a$ for which there is some $b$ such that $(a,\ b)$ is in $f$. If $a$ is a function, it follows from the definition that there is, in fact, a *unique* number $b$ such that $(a,\ b)$ is in $f$. This unique number is denoted as $f(x)$.

The intuition behinds this definition using ordered pairs is that, in fact, a function is a set of all ordered pairs $(x,\ f(x))$ such that $f(x)$ for $x$. As a result, mathematicians can know simply the collection of ordered pairs instead of ambiguous rules or association in order to "know all about the function".

Notes
Btw Spivak's *Calculus* is no ordinary calculus textbook but with intense proofs and rigorous math. You might want to take a book on logic or mathematical proof writing to move on.